# Better approach to find Nth term of the sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Given :

```
    I : a positive integer
    n : a positive integer
```

nth Term of sequence for input = I :

```
    F(I,1) = (I * (I+1)) / 2
    F(I,2) = F(I,1) + F(I-1,1) + F(I-2,1) + .... F(2,1) + F(1,1)
    F(I,3) = F(I,2) + F(I-1,2) + F(I-2,2) + .... F(2,2) + F(2,1)
    ..
    ..
    F(I,n) = F(I,n-1) + F(I-1,n-1) + F(I-2,n-1) + .... F(2,n-1) + F(1,n-1)
    nth term --> F(I,n)
```

Approach 1 : Used recursion to find the above :

```
def recursive_sum(I, n):
    if n == 1:
        return (I * (I + 1)) // 2
    else:
        return sum(recursive_sum(j, n - 1) for j in range(I, 0, -1))
```

Approach 2 : Iteration to store reusable values in a dictionary. Used this dictionary to get the nth term.:

```
def non_recursive_sum_using_data(I, n):
    global data
    if n == 1:
        return (I * (I + 1)) // 2
    else:
        return sum(data[j][n - 1] for j in range(I, 0, -1))

def iterate(I,n):
    global data
    data = {}
    i = 1
    j = 1   
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(I+1):
            if j not in data:
                data[j] = {}
            data[j][i] = recursive_sum(j,i)
    return data[I][n]
```

The recursion approach is obviously not efficient due to maximum recursion depth. Also the next approach's time and space complexity will be poor.

Is there better way to recurse ? or a different approach than recursion ?
I am curious if we can find a formula for nth term.

Comment: Your recursive sum function isn't recursive in approach 2

Answer (score 1):

You could just [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) your recursive results:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def recursive_sum(I, n):
    if n == 1:
        return (I * (I + 1)) // 2
    return sum(recursive_sum(j, n - 1) for j in range(I, 0, -1))
```

That way you can get the readability and brevity of the recursive approach without most of the performance issues since the function is only called once for each argument combination `(I, n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the usual `binomial(n,k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)`, you have
`F(I,n) = binomial(I+n, n+1)`.

Then you can choose the method you like most to compute binomial coefficients.

Here an example:

```
def binomial(n, k):
    numerator = denominator = 1 
    t = max(k, n-k) 
    for low,high in enumerate(range(t+1, n+1), 1): 
        numerator *= high 
        denominator *= low 
    return numerator // denominator

def F(I,n): return binomial(I+n, n+1)
```

Comment: damned all that verbose stuff I wrote for something so simple. May I ask how you came up with binomial(I+n, n+1)?

Comment: I just computed the first 10x10 matrix and looked at the numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the nth term of the sequence is the one you have already mentioned.
Also rightly so you have identified that it will lead to an inefficient algorithm and stack overflow.

You can look into dynamic programming approach where u calculate F(I,N) just once and just reuse the value.

For example this is how the fibonacci seq is calculated. 
[just-example] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/
You need to find the same pattern and cache the value

I have an example for this here in this small code written in golang 
https://play.golang.org/p/vRi-QMj7z2v

Comment: The question isn't using the classic Fibonacci number calculation, though.

Comment: Ohh sorry my wordings were not correct, I meant to give Fibonacci as example. 
Basic idea being using some kind of memorisation or caching for already calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

#### the standard DP

One can do a (tiny) bit of math to rewrite your function:

```
F(i,n) = sum_{k=0}^{i-1} F(i-k, n-1) = sum_{k=1}^{i} F(k, n-1)
```

Now notice, that if you consider a matrix `F_{ixn}`, to compute `F(i,n)` we just need to add the elements of the previous column.

```
x----+---
|    + |
|----+ |
|----+-F(i,n)
```

We conclude that we can build the first layer (aka column). Then the second one. And so forth until we get to the n-th layer.

Finally we take the last element of our final layer which is `F(i,n)`

The computation time is about `O(I*n)`

#### More math based but faster

An other way is to consider our layer as a vector variable `X`.
We can write the recurrence relation as

```
X_n = MX_{n-1}
```

where `M` is a triangular matrix with `1` in the lower part.

We then want to compute the general term of `X_n` so we want to compute `M^n`.

By following [Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079950/compute-the-n-th-power-of-triangular-3-times3-matrix)

(I just copy from the link above)

Coefficients should be indiced `_{n+1}` and `_n`, but here it is `_1` and '' for readability

Moreover the matrix is upper triangular but we can just take the transpose afterwards...

```
a_1 b_1 c_1 d_1   1 1 1 1   a b c d
    a_1 b_1 c_1 = 0 1 1 1 * 0 a b c
        a_1 b_1   0 0 1 1   0 0 a b
            a_1   0 0 0 1   0 0 0 a
```

by going from last row to first:

- `a = 1`
- from `b_1 = a+b = 1 + b = n`, `b = n`
- from `c_1 = a+b+c = 1+n+c`, `c = n(n+1)/2`
- from `d_1 = a+b+c+d = 1+n+n(n+1)/2 +d, d = n(n+1)(n+2)/6`

**I have not proved it** but I hint that `e_1 = n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/24` (so basically `C_n^k`)
(I think the proof lies more in the fact that `F(i,n) = F(i,n-1) + F(i-1,n)` )

More generally instead of taking variables `a,b,c`... but `X_n(0)`, `X_n(1)`...

```
X_n(0) = 1
X_n(i) = n*...*(n+i-1) / i!
```

And by applying recusion for computing X:

```
X_n(0) = 1
X_n(i) = X_n(i-1)*(n+i-1)/i
```

Finally we deduce `F(i,n)` as the scalar product `Y_{n-1} * X_1` where `Y_n` is the reversed vector of `X_n` and `X_1(n) = n*(n+1)/2`

---

```
from functools import lru_cache
#this is copypasted from schwobaseggl
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def recursive_sum(I, n):
    if n == 1:
        return (I * (I + 1)) // 2
    return sum(recursive_sum(j, n - 1) for j in range(I, 0, -1))


def iterative_sum(I,n):
    layer = [ i*(i+1)//2 for i in range(1,I+1)]
    x = 2
    while x <= n:
        next_layer = [layer[0]]
        for i in range(1,I):
            #we don't need to compute all the sum everytime
            #take the previous sum and add it the new number
            next_layer.append( next_layer[i-1] + layer[i] )
        layer = next_layer

        x += 1
    return layer[-1]

def brutus(I,n):
    if n == 1:
        return I*(I+1)//2

    X_1 = [ i*(i+1)//2 for i in range(1, I+1)]
    X_n = [1]
    for i in range(1, I):
        X_n.append(X_n[-1] * (n-1 + i-1) / i )

    X_n.reverse()
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, I):
        s += X_1[i]*X_n[i]
    return s

def do(k,n):
    print('rec', recursive_sum(k,n))
    print('it ', iterative_sum(k,n))
    print('bru', brutus(k,n))
    print('---')

do(1,4)
do(2,1)
do(3,2)
do(4,7)
do(7,4)
```